# How to customize json response for BadCredentials Exception in Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I want to customize the json response for BadCredential Exception (Error 401 Unauthorized) in Spring security.

Current json:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1558062843375,
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid credentials!",
    "path": "/Test/api/v1/consultas/ddjj"
}
```

New format:

```
{
    "codigo": "Invalid",
    "mensaje": "Invalid credentials!"
}
```

I have tried by adding a Authentication Entry Point to my security config class but it didn't work. I'm only able to catch the 403 error but not the 401.

```
@Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();

            http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, e)
                    -> {
                response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                JSONObject respuesta = new JSONObject();
                respuesta.put("codigo", "Invalid");
                respuesta.put("mensaje", "Invalid credentials!");
                response.getWriter().write(respuesta.toJSONString());
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationException` class gives you access to exceptions related to Authentication. In my application, I created a `RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class to handle all REST API exceptions and added a method to handle AuthenticationException class exceptions. You can customize the REST API response here. Please see the following implementation

**RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java**

```
import com.pj.springsecurity.exceptions.exceptions.GenericException;
import com.pj.springsecurity.model.exception.ErrorMessage;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler(ModelMapper modelMapper)
    {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Authentication Failed", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(GenericException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleGenericExceptions(GenericException genericException, WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage=modelMapper.map(genericException,ErrorMessage.class);
        errorMessage.setStatusCode(errorMessage.getStatus().value());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage,errorMessage.getStatus());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> handleAllExceptions(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage=modelMapper.map(exception,ErrorMessage.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Please see [this class](https://github.com/pavankjadda/SpringSecurity-SpringData/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pj/springsecurity/exceptions/handlers/RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java) for more details and let me know if you have any questions regarding this